# How to map NSButton to Int using dictionaries

Tags: swift

I have an interface with a lot of buttons. I would like to put them in a dictionary to map them to numbers.

I tried the following:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow
    @IBOutlet var number0 : NSButton
    @IBOutlet var number1 : NSButton
    @IBOutlet var number2 : NSButton
    @IBOutlet var number3 : NSButton
    @IBOutlet var number4 : NSButton
    @IBOutlet var number5 : NSButton
    @IBOutlet var number6 : NSButton
    @IBOutlet var number7 : NSButton
    @IBOutlet var number8 : NSButton
    @IBOutlet var number9 : NSButton

    var number = Dictionary<NSButton, Int>()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        number = [number0: 0]
    }

}
```

The code above compiles fine (Retina MBP 2.6GHz i7) but when I run it, it throws an error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

If I change the `Int` to `AnyObject` like this

```
var number = Dictionary<NSButton, AnyObject >()
```

It works just fine.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: what happens if you cast the 0 as an Int?

Comment: I get the exact same error

Answer (score 1):

Try using Integer in your dictionary instead.

```
var number = Dictionary<UIButton, Integer>()
```

Integer is the protocol that Int implements. I'm not exactly sure why this works.